# Predatory journal threatens me to either pay or they will retract the paper visibly online

Tags: publications, withdraw, retraction

I accidentally submitted to a predatory journal from the Pulsus Group, which is on [Beall's List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beall%27s_List). I did not sign anything yet; no copyright transferred. I then tried to withdraw when I found out about their predatory nature. They want to charge me 525 € as a last offer to either publish or withdraw by Monday so as not to retract the paper publicly. They only have a PDF version of it. How bad would the damage of public retraction from a predatory journal be, and can I resubmit it elsewhere afterwards?

If I pay, they could still continue to extort me… they are bombarding me with emails to pay.

Comment: Since copyright has not been transferred, you can submit it elsewhere. Does this answer your question? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17374/how-can-i-withdraw-a-publication-from-a-predatory-fake-journal-and-resubmit-to

Comment: Do you have some legal protection insurance to discuss this with a lawyer? After all you signed no contract - it would be more about character defamation in this case.

Comment: Yes I know. But maybe they would defame me out of anger if I don’t pay… I am already talking to lawyers, but no legal insurance unfortunately and would be more expensive than paying the scammers. The question would be how bad retraction from a predatory journal would influence the chance to publish the paper elsewhere or destroy reputation. Maybe these are just bluffs of course… and they won’t publish or retract.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can I submit in a new journal after submission in a predatory journal who force to pay in order to withdraw?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/148856/can-i-submit-in-a-new-journal-after-submission-in-a-predatory-journal-who-force)

Comment: see also: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/123408/do-i-have-an-obligation-to-pay-publication-fee-to-predatory-journal

Comment: I don't understand the scenario. The predatory publisher hasn't published your paper, and does not even have the rights to do so. How can a paper that was never published in the first place be retracted?

Comment: ... and if indeed you have not signed anything yet, there is little basis for the journal to claim that you have made any kind of agreement with them that could subject you to liability if you broke it.  But do be careful about that: it is possible that you *did* make an agreement, and even did an equivalent of signing it, by the action of clicking the journal's "Submit my article" button.

Comment: The worry "maybe they would defame me out of anger if I don’t pay" would be enough for me to run the other way. Thugs. "Publishing" with them is a public announcement that your material **does not otherwise meet high standards**. Why advertise that?

Comment: Beall's List is in past tense [on Wikipidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beall%27s_List#Removal). Is that true, and if so, how does it affect this question? Presumably, the information is 7 years out of date.

Comment: "If I pay, they could still continue to bribe me…" - did you mean *extort* you, or something like that? If they are *bribing* you, that would mean *they* give *you* money so that you will do something in return.

Comment: Yes I mean extort. And yes it could be possible, that I gave them copyright accidentally. They wanted me to sign a formal copyright declaration, which I refused, but they state in their policy that by submitting the copyright is theirs, which I did not read and yes I clicked on it in the false and dumb believe the journal was not predatory. But they indeed threat to publish and retract, which is confusing. I will see, if they do that, but I refuse to pay scammers.

Comment: @GeraldineGera404Reichard What jurisdiction is the company or individual running the journal in? Ditto yourself?

Comment: @GeraldineGera404Reichard if they do publish and retract, bear in mind that nobody will care.  Anybody that knows that it was a predatory journal ought to be able to work out that it was not retracted on quality ("cui bono") - or it may be that they are taking advantage of the predatory nature and won't care.  For those that don't know it is a predatory journal, it may cause them to question the quality of the journal, which is no bad thing.  I have a paper with a publisher on Beale's list (*but from a decade before there was a list), it is no big deal, especially if you are early career.

Comment: BTW do you have any evidence that they failed to perform their part of the agreement for your specific paper (e.g. they promised peer review but didn't actually send it for review)?  For the copyright issue, you may want to ask on the Law SE - I suspect a substantial re-wording of the paper would circumvent the copyright, which is on the text/diagrams not the ideas, however I am not an expert on that so don't rely on my understanding!

Comment: I looked up the publisher in question, and the main evidence for it being predatory seems to be that it was bought up by OMICS, and that seems to have caused a lack of confidence in it's editors and associated medical institutions.  I don't think that is strong evidence that it actually *is* a predatory journal, it seems that it was on Beale's list as being potentially predatory.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsus_Group .  I suspect they were once solid journals (if perhaps not that prestigious).

Comment: So they are going to publish without copyrights when you didn't give permission to publish and then withdraw it to make you look bad?  That's the most bizarre extortion scheme I have ever heard.

Answer (score 38):

The truth is, *no one* can really predict what the journal will do. However, there are several things to keep in mind:

1. predatory journals are in the business of making money with the least effort for themselves
2. retractions potentially harm the journal in addition to the author
3. it makes no sense for a journal to retract a paper unless they have already published it.
4. threats and bluster cost the journal nothing

You don't say whether they have in fact already published your paper but it would seem truly strange that they would go to the expense of publishing your paper if they have not already done so, only with the intention of retracting it ... and still not getting any money from you.

With that in mind, in your shoes I would simply ***stop responding*** to any correspondence from them, submit your paper elsewhere.

One last thing ... I don't think that places like [Retraction Watch](https://retractionwatch.com/) deign to cover junk journals!

Comment: Thanks. That seems like the right thing to do. For now they have not even “peer-reviewed” it nor published, but threat me to do this on Monday, if I won’t pay. I guess there would have not really peer-review it in any case, but it is officially in review stage. They wanted me to sign the copyright agreement to proceed with the peer review, which I refused to do.

Comment: To me, that seems like the best call. Put differently, if I were in your shoes, I ***would*** do exactly as I suggested. The future is unpredictable, but surrendering to blackmail never does one any good. And I strongly suspect that the journal will move on to an easier victim if they can't quickly get money from you! And as I implied, I'd just ignore their future emails, not start arguing with them or abusing them.

Comment: Yes seems like the best option . Thanks.

Comment: Right now they are bombarding me with emails to pay, so I guess that’s all that they will do. Hoping for the best. But you cannot really argue with scammers that’s true.

Comment: +1. This journal almost certainly sends out threatening emails like that to anyone who sends them a manuscript, since *threats do not cost them anything*. At some point, if they tailor their threats to Germans, they will start telling you that they will send an *Inkassobüro* after you. This is all bluster. They are spamming people and hoping that one in twenty victims will pay them. Cut off contact with them, and submit elsewhere.

Comment: And should they indeed send someone to collect the money, I am sure there is the analog of "cease and desist" in Germany. As long as you did not sign a copyright agreement, I think you are in a pretty good state. 'Sittenwidrig' may also be a term of interest in a potential legal dispute of the nature of their business, but I do not think it will escalate to legal. These guys know that Germans are afraid of legal, and so that's the game they play.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs sittenwidrig isn't quite specific to this case. Whether it is or not, maybe, but that's details really. Sure, there is a cease and desist. They won't send an Inkassobüro, because they have to pay it upfront and it will leave you in peace if you refuse to pay. An Inkassobüro is meant to get money that someone actually owes. They are good at getting some money out of you instead of none, if you have no money.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I thought that it might be a potential defense appropriately interpreted in the context of the situation, but I am not a lawyer. In any case, I agree, unlikely that they can actually do anything.

Comment: I don’t think that they can send anyone after me, since they have no right to do so, not yet threatened with legal steps and have nothing except a Pdf of the paper. They now try desperately to lowered the price of withdrawal or publishing to 400$ in their latest spam mails to get at least some money out of me. If they really would publish and retract the paper, they maybe say, that they will put it offline again, if I’ll pay. Or its just a bluff. But who cares about retraction from those kind of journals?

Answer (score 7):

Get a lawyer involved. I would not simply ghost them and hope they won't do anything, and you definitely shouldn't keep arguing with them. If you are a student or academic at a university or a researcher at a research institute or company, your organisation will have lawyers who are knowledgeable about contracts and copyright law. It is likely that a sternly worded letter from your lawyer will see the end of the matter.

Comment: Yes, if you are at a US university this is something the university legal office would probably handle for you.

Comment: (+1) for advice to get a lawyer involved.  However, whether a lawyer letter will dispose of the matter might depend on the jurisdiction which the predatory journal operates in.  If it is a "hostile" country then the courts there might not be terribly amenable to actions against the publisher, so the letter will carry little threatening weight.

Comment: I am German not US. I don’t think lawyers can do much, since these people are criminals and don’t care about laws. Also the information about the journal on the website seems like they use fake names and operate from some third world country. The lawyers demanded high prices. One lawyer even said 300€ an hour and I should better pay the scammers. Also Pulsus had several lawsuits to deal with and still seem to operate. They could always still retract the paper publicly, if that would have any impact, if a pdf version and a journal website are enough to do so.

Comment: As OP says, the typical spam journal operates from countries outside the reach of western law. Getting a lawyer seems like expenses that will ultimately not be helpful. OTOH this also seriously limits what *they* can realistically do to *you* - put a mean note on their website? Who cares, nobody takes them seriously anyway (that's why it's a spam publisher).

Comment: Geraldine, you almost certainly have access to a lawyer at no cost through your institution, assuming that you are a student or employed as a researcher. Ask your supervisor or check your intranet pages to find out their contact details. It is worth asking someone familiar with the relevant laws for advice.

Comment: Just to add: universities have lawyers everywhere. This advice is not specific to the US.

Comment: Ok I will try to. Cannot be harmful…

Comment: @Significance another question is whether those university lawyers will be willing to help you for free. It is not at all obvious.

Comment: @wimi if the paper is going to be published with the university’s affiliation, they have an interest in looking after the university’s reputation. It’s their job.

Answer (score 1):

Just playing devil's advocate, but lets say you submitted a paper to a reputable journal and it had been accepted and published online, and the author refused to pay the agreed publication fee†.  It would not be unreasonable for them to "threaten" to withdraw the paper and leave a note to explain why.  What else should they do, given that they had published the work for you, as agreed?

Predatory publishers exists because they meet a need.  Some academics need to get papers in print, whether competently peer reviewed or not, perhaps for career progression reasons.  How is the publisher to know whether or not you agreed for them to publish your paper knowing what the journals standards are like.

At the end of the day, there is an element of "caveat emptor" (buyer beware).  You seem to agree that you made a mistake in sending the paper to a predatory journal, so you should expect there to be some consequences to your mistake.  I would send them a letter *requesting* them to withdraw your paper (or agreeing to the withdrawal).  Call their bluff.  If someone asked me why the paper was withdrawn, I would just say "yes, I discovered it was a predatory journal after I had submitted the paper".  If they give a false reason for the withdrawal, then you should have the reviewer comments and email from the editor showing that it was not because of a problem with the content.

† It amazes me that commercial academic publishers still exist, give that reputable on-line journals, such as jmlr.org have demonstrated it is feasible to have an open access journal that is free to both reader and author, as most of the work is done pro-bono by academic anyway.  It would be a much better use of taxpayers money for the funding bodies to subsidise similar academic-run on-line journals (the quality of the journal will depend on the quality of the editorial board).

Comment: It is _not_ reasonable for a reputable journal to retract an article for unpaid fees. Nothing in the [COPE retraction guidelines](https://publicationethics.org/retraction-guidelines) says you should, and I haven't seen it done. The publisher can go as far as to sue you for unpaid bills, but there is nothing wrong with the paper itself, and thus holding it hostage is improper.

Comment: @user71659 is there anything in the COPE guidelines that say that they shouldn't?  I think there is a terminological issue here, where "retraction" has the implication that there was something wrong with the paper.  Simply deleting the paper from the online journal leaving an explanation of why it was done would not be a retraction in that sense, so I don't see a problem with it - it wouldn't be a criticism of the content of the paper.

Comment: Reputable journals don't publish your paper before you've paid the fee, if there  is one.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151818/discussion-on-answer-by-dikran-marsupial-predatory-journal-threatens-me-to-eithe); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.